# Object disposed exception when returning File

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, stream, npgsql

I have the following code in my **.NET Core 3.1** project. My goal is to avoid loading the file into RAM by using streams.

```cs
public IActionResult Download(int id)
{
    using (var transaction = _dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        using (NpgsqlLargeObjectStream stream = _dbContext.GetLargeObjectStream(id))
        {
            // 1st method - works
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                stream.CopyTo(ms);
                return File(ms.ToArray(), "application/octet-stream", "test.txt");
            }

            // 2nd method - doesn't work 
            //return File(stream, "application/octet-stream", "test.txt");
        }
    }
}

public NpgsqlLargeObjectStream GetLargeObjectStream(int oid)
{
    Database.OpenConnection();
    var manager = new NpgsqlLargeObjectManager(Database.GetDbConnection() as NpgsqlConnection);
    return manager.OpenRead(Convert.ToUInt32(oid));
}
```

If I use the **first method**, everything works normally and file is downloaded. I don't like this approach since file is loaded into RAM first. It doesn't work well if files are large (1GB+).

If I use the **second method**, I get the following exception:

```
InvalidOperationException: Object disposed
Npgsql.NpgsqlLargeObjectStream.CheckDisposed()
```

What am I doing wrong? Also, how can I commit transaction after the stream has been successfully read to the end by `return File`?

Comment: Does Database.OpenConnection(); return any value?

Comment: No, it's a `void` function.

Comment: Is connection a NpgsqlConnection?

Comment: Which connection do you mean? `Database.GetDbConnection()` returns `DbConnection` and then I cast it to `NpgsqlConnection`. I use `EF Core` with `Npgsql` driver for `PostgreSQL`. Function `GetLargeObjectStream` is placed inside `DbContext` **partial** class so I can call it wherever I have access to `DbContext`.

Comment: You are getting an Invalid operation exception.  It looks like it is due to the connection being disposed (probably never successfully opened).  Is connection already open and you are trying to open 2nd time?

Comment: If connection wasn't successfully opened, how would then 1st method work? I removed `Database.OpenConnection();` and tried 2nd method - still the same exception when returning `File`.

Comment: Why are you converting to `UInt32`? In the first approach you are directly passing in an `int`.

Comment: I don't understand. Both methods are wrapped in the same `using` statement (created with `_dbContext.GetLargeObjectStream(id)`). Here, `id` is `int` in both cases.

Comment: If it is a stream don't you want to return stream.ReadAllBytes();

Comment: Doesn’t that read everything into RAM? What if file is 1GB large and 100 users do it at the same time?